# Multithreading - Duplicate key exception during insert

Tags: java, multithreading, hibernate, spring-data

I have a problem when i try to create datas in multithreading environment. Before calling super.create() i check if data not already exists in database. But i believe that threads call in same time the method create() and one of them fail throwing a duplicate key exception instead of a IllegalArgumentException :

```
    @Transactional(readOnly=false)
    @Override
    public T create(T resource){

      //check if data already exists
      if(this.repository.findById(resource.getId()) != null){
         throw new IllegalArgumentException("Resource already exists");
      }

      //else call create
      return super.create(resource);
    }
```

Is there any mean to make it works? The project use spring-data-jpa with Hibernate 4.3.1.Final and Oracle database

PS : I need a smarter solution than only catch the exception because i have the same problem during the update and i have to check the integration date to update or not the resource if the resource date is more recent than the one present in database.

And my project have to run on multiple nodes.

Thanks

Comment: what id generation strategy are you using?

Comment: Hi, i'm using sequence generator strategy but the duplicate key is not really on the id field, the code above is not exactly the code i'm using. Actually the check is on another field called applicationId (findByApplicationId) which have a unique constraint on it.

Comment: is the value for that other field coming from user input? or is it generated as well? another question more related to the answers you got so far: are you running in a cluster? in case you have multiple nodes thread synchronization will not help.

Comment: Value comes from user input ans yes i need to have several instances of my project running...

Comment: Usually, Identity generation strategy can be used in case of clustered environment or on this case. DB will auto increment the id for u.

Comment: Hi, it's not an increment problem the column which has the unique constraint comes from an user input

Comment: In this case I would rather catch the DataIntegrityViolationException in your service layer (assuming you are calling the repo method from a service bean). No need for any checks beforehand.

Answer (score 1):

You could harden your method using double-checked locking (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) with synchronization to ensure that there will be only one created object and other threads simply skip the creation. The trick is to check for existence of the object, then enter a synchronized block and then checking for a second time.

Pseudocode:

```
if (noObjectExists()) {
    synchronized {
        if (noObjectExists()) {
            // Create object
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks but what about performance ? All my services use this generic method (create)

Comment: Integrity vs. performance ;-) Seriously, if the creation is no long-running task, after the first thread creating the entity, the subsequent threads only check for existence and return immediately.

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that there is only one `resource` for single `resource.id` you can lock on `resource` object.

```
@Transactional(readOnly=false)
@Override
public T create(T resource){
    synchronized (resource) {
        //check if data already exists
        if(this.repository.findById(resource.getId()) != null){
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Resource already exists");
        }

        //else call create
        return super.create(resource);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks i will try it tomorrow, I thought this solution but i'm afraid about performance

Answer (score 0):

**Insertion**

- U may use AtomicInteger for unique key for that

**Updation**

- Multithread  updation one of the painful job. You can use synchroization block. But this also one of performance overhead. Updation wait for unnecessary rows even its not related  to this. So we can create a lock against unique column. So Same row wont update twice. Also in Hibernate we can fetch object and update in sync block.